# Implementing a Short-Cut Function to Replace mysqli_real_escape_string()

Tags: php, mysqli

I want to implement a short-cut function to replace the commonly used `mysqli_real_escape_string()` as follow in a **separate script** that will be included to my main script:

```
 $cxn = mysqli_connect($hostname, $username, $password, $databasename) 
  or die ("Couldn't connect to server.");

 function m($str) {return "'".mysqli_real_escape_string($cxn, $str)."'";}
```

The **main script** contains `foreach` that will loop through the array as follows:

```
 foreach($ARRAY as $field => $value)
 {
  $fields[] = $field;
  $value = strip_tags(trim($value));
  $values[] = m($value); // function m() is implemented here
 }
```

Upon inspecting the SQL statement, I find that all the inserted values are empty. I know that if no connection is open, `mysqli_real_escape_string()` will return an empty string, so this could be the problem. However, if I were to replace the following line

```
$values[] = m($value);
```

with this,

```
$values[] = "'".mysqli_real_escape_string($cxn, $value)."'";
```

all the proper values are returned. So, what could be the reason causing my short-cut function `m()` to fail?

Comment: It's failing because of the scope - the function `m()` doesn't have access to the global variable `$cxn` - you'd either have to reference it from the global scope `$GLBOALS['cxn']` or pass it in as an argument ... personally I'd encapsulate the whole lot in an object mind.

Comment: have you tried array_walk_recursive() http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk-recursive.php ?

Comment: I became aware of functions like array_walk and array_map quite recently only, haven't really look into them in detail. I understand what you are getting at, I will work to improve my code at later stage. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$cxn = mysqli_connect();
function e($string)
{
    global $cxn;
    return mysqli_real_escape_string($string, $cxn);
}
```

Comment: `$GLOBALS['cxn']` would be better

Answer (score 1):

the reason is as simple as *variable scope.*

so, if this function is going to be a class member, just change `$cxn` to `$this->cxn`;
otherwise there is no point in this function at all: it is agreed that using placeholders is better than calling escaping function manually.

Also, I am curious, why don't you do something to $fields too?

Comment: I am not using OOP for my PHP script. What do you mean by using placeholders? Fields are not user input, so I thought it is not necessary to escape. Any security issue?

Comment: there is always a security issue. even if you *think* there isn't

Comment: Can you quote me an example? I am interested to know more :)

Comment: some of them can be mysql keywords, if you want an example

Comment: I am also wondering what is that $ARRAY which values are user input and keys are not

Comment: Oh, because after extracting from $_POST, I did a `compact()` on the fields to form `$ARRAY`. I thought this is secure enough. If not, I would like to find out.

Comment: what's the point in compacting the same data from one array into another? and where is security in that?

Comment: In compact(), the fields are specified by me, any attempt by user at changing the fields would not be accepted into $ARRAY.

Comment: I still can't see the point. if you have already fields compacted, what is `$fields[] = $field;` code for?

Comment: The `$fields[]` and `$values[]` are used with `implode()` for creating the SQL statement as I have many elements. Sorry if I have confused you. I still want to know if after using compact() there is still a security issue. Thanks :)

Comment: your way of dealing with POST variables is so twisted and unnatural so it's hard to see any point in your manipulations. So, you are using extract() with POST and then compact()? extract come to the point of danger then. and whole mess looks weird.

Comment: Yes, it does looks unorthodox. You are right that extract could be a problem. I wonder why many books still teach people to do plain extract. Thanks for pointing out, I will clean up my codes. ;p